# Trying to remake linux find command in C

Tags: c, linux, find, filesystems

I've been tasked with remaking a portion of the functionality of the find command. The first part I'm trying to do is just the normal "find " where it lists all files and sub-directories within that directory. I'm using the actual find command to test my results.

Anything apparent that I'm missing that's causing me to print improper file paths?

Image Order:

1. C Code
2. Expected Output
3. Actual Output
4. Tree for the directory I'm using to test

   ```
   void readSub (char* subDir)
   {
    DIR *sub_dp = opendir(subDir); //Opens directory stream

    struct dirent *subDirp; //define sub directory pointer
    struct stat buf; //define file status struct

    char t1[] = ".";
    char t2[] = "..";
    char t3[] = "/";

    if(sub_dp != NULL) // Was directory successfully opened
    {
            //read each entry one time only
            while((subDirp = readdir(sub_dp)) != NULL)
            {
                    char *temp = subDirp -> d_name; //check if first entry was a sub directory

                    //avoid searching for . and ..
                    if(strcmp(temp, t1) != 0 && strcmp(temp, t2) != 0)
                    {
                            char *tempSub = t3;
                            tempSub = strcat(tempSub, temp); //add / to entry name
                            char *temp_full_path = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2000);
                            temp_full_path = strcpy(temp_full_path, subDir);
                            strcat(temp_full_path, tempSub); //gives full path

                            printf("%s\n", temp_full_path);
                            DIR *subsubDP = opendir(temp_full_path); //try to open

                            if(subsubDP != NULL) //if not NULL then subsubDP is sub directory
                            {
                                    closedir(subsubDP); //will get opened in recursive call
                                    readSub(temp_full_path); //recursive call
                            }
                    }
            } //end of while loop
            closedir(sub_dp); //close directory stream
    }

    else
    {
            printf("Can't open directory\n");
            exit(2);
    }
   }

   int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
           char *dir;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
            dir = ".";
    }

    else
    {
            dir = argv[1];
    }

    readSub(dir);

    exit(0);
   }
   ```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `tempSub = strcat(tempSub, temp);` is not valid. The array that `tempSub` points to only has room for 1 character (not including the null terminator), you can't concatenate anything to it. This buffer overflow causes undefined behavior.

Comment: So in that case do I need to define t3 as a string instead of a char? and then change char *tempSub to string *tempSub?

Comment: Is there any good reason why you're not using something like `ftw` or `fts`?

Comment: @Cheatah I'm unaware of what those are unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is

```
tempSub = strcat(tempSub, temp); //add / to entry name
```

`tempSub` points to the `t3` array, which only has 2 bytes. Concatenating `temp` to it writes outside the array bounds, which causes undefined behavior.

You should calculate the total length of `temp_full_path` by adding the lengths of `subDir`, `t3`, `temp`, plus 1 for the null terminator, and allocate that. Since you only need this within the current loop iteration, you can use a variable-length array rather than `malloc()` (your code never calls `free(temp_full_path)`).

Replace

```
 char *tempSub = t3;
 tempSub = strcat(tempSub, temp); //add / to entry name
 char *temp_full_path = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2000);
 temp_full_path = strcpy(temp_full_path, subDir);
 strcat(temp_full_path, tempSub); //gives full path
```

with

```
char temp_full_path[strlen(subDir) + strlen(t3) + strlen(temp) + 1];
sprintf(temp_full_path, "%s%s%s", subDir, t3, temp);
```

Comment: Where is this code getting placed and what is it replacing? I'm just getting compilation errors

Comment: I've updated the answer to show what it replaces